# How to add reviewers to GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I created a repository on GitHub and want to add a couple of friends to review my pull requests.

I used this [source](https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review/) and when I enter the names of some GitHub users the Reviewers bar stays empty.

How to add arbitrary reviewers to my GitHub repository?

Comment: Do they have read access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send the pull request link to your friends, then they can click the files changed button at the top:
[image: screenshot]

Then, they can look through the diffs, and click the blue plus button on any line where they want to leave a comment:

[image: other screenshot]

Then they can click it, and add a comment and start a review:
[image: more screenshots]

You don't need to formally invite them since anyone that can read the repository can review pull requests. If you want to give them a github notification, you can mention them in the comments.